# Intellij switch tab to other options

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been looking up this thing but I couldn't find the answer for it. Consider this image:

[image]

How can I choose on "New Window" using keyboard? When I press "Tab" the tab changes to "New Window" but after pressing "Enter" the project opens in "This Window". I would like to select "New Window" using shortcut key or just keys.

Comment: When you press Alt you will notice the `_` appearing on the options. You can use `W` in this case to select new window.

Comment: Man you are a life saver :)